# EF Core - How to add a record INSTANTLY when DbContext instance is created only once

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to add a default record(administrator identities) instantly when DbContext instance is craeted. However, I tried to add corresponding logic on `OnModelCreating` and `OnConfiguring` methods but no success. both of the methods are complaining:

> A DbContext instance cannot be used inside 'OnConfiguring' since it is
> still being configured at this point
>
> A DbContext instance cannot be used inside 'OnModelCreating' in any
> way that makes use of the model that is being created

More importantly, I don't want that the corresponding logic(adding default record) to be called & checked more than once (unnecessary overhead). the logic shown below:

```
if (UserList.Find("admin") == null){
    UserList.Add(new UserItem() { co_id = "1", username = "admin", name = "admin", password = "123", admin = true });
    SaveChanges();
}
```

where do I put this piece of code and call it only once when Model is created?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I suspect there's a misunderstanding of what a DbContext is and how it woks. A DbContext works *disconnected*, just like a DataTable or DataSet. It's not a database connection any more than those classes. It only connects when it needs to read data, or when it needs to persist all its changes when `SaveChanges` is called. Which, by the way, is *not* meant to be called after every modification. By doing this, it increases scaleability by orders of magnitude by long lived locks and blocking. It also offers "free" transactions - just don't save to discard changes

Comment: So it makes no sense to try to write anything when a DbContext is created - it hasn't done anything yet and may not do anything at all. A DbContext is *short-lived*, which means you'll be creating instances all the time. If you don't, it's probably a design bug that will quickly lead to serious problems.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, so you mean there is no way to have only once call&check? so what's the best way?

Comment: What is the *real* problem you want to solve? EF is how you think you can solve it, not the actual problem. You describe what you think the solution is, not the problem. EF is an ORM, its job is not to offer generic database access, it's to map objects to tables.  If you want to audit or log **EF Core** operations, [there are several ways](only once call&check) including logging, events and interceptors that can handle command and connection events. If you want to log or audit the start of an operation, you have no objects to map, just a record to write. You could just use ADO.NET

Comment: On the other hand, for recording business events, the appropriate features are *logging* and *tracing*. Instead of hard-coding database writes whenever you want to record an operation, you could use a logging provider that writes specific events to a database, like Serilog's [SQL Server sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver). Or you could use .NET Core's [built-in Activities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/distributed-tracing-instrumentation-walkthroughs) to trace operations in the application or across services

Comment: Oops, the correct link to EF Core's logging, events and interceptors is [Overview of Logging and Interception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for your comments I have to read more about them to post a comment. I will feedback you soon

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I posted an answer and will be glad to have your idea.

Comment: So you wanted to add some initial data for the application, not insert anything when a DbContext is first created. That's a very different question and yes, migrations are one way to go. Or your application's deployment script/package could make the necessary insertions. If you use a database project or database deployment scripts, you'd do that in a post-deployment script. This is a case of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you want to use deploy some initial data but instead of asking about this, you asked about the DbContext

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't believe it's an XY Problem because I openly stated I want to insert data by `DbContext` even I put the logic I tried and it was clear that I am using `DbContext` and when I want to use it so it must be instantiated first. So my main concern which I said was that I don't want the logic repeated over and over when I read about `onModelCreating` I found that the `DbContext` is cached  and the logic won't repeat over and over for each http request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative way to do what you're trying to do is use migrations. Create an empty migration or use an existing migration. You can either use [OnModelCreating()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating?view=entity-framework-5.0.0) or [Sql()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder.sql?view=efcore-5.0) for this. But **make sure to hash your passwords** before storing them in the database.

**1. Using Sql()**

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "Users",
        columns: table => new
        {
            Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
            Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
            Username = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
            Password = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true),
            Admin = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_Users", x => x.Id);
        });

    #region CustomInsertUsing_Sql()
    migrationBuilder.Sql(@"
         SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Users] ON
         INSERT INTO [dbo].[Users] ([Id], [Name], [Username], [Password], [Admin]) VALUES (1, N'Admin', N'Admin', N'123', 1)
         SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Users] OFF
    ");
    #endregion
}
```

**2. Using OnModelCreating()**

In your database context class, add `OnModelCreating` method and use `HasData` to configure seed record.

```
using DataSeedingSample.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DataSeedingSample.Data
{
    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options) {}
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasData(
            new User { 
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Admin",
                Username = "Admin",
                Password = "123",
                Admin = true 
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Now add a migration, which will create the following migration.

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.InsertData(
        table: "Users",
        columns: new[] { "Id", "Admin", "Name", "Password", "Username" },
        values: new object[] { 1, true, "Admin", "123", "Admin" });
}
```

Whatever method from above (`Sql()` or `OnModelCreating()`) you used, now you have a migration with the record you want to seed.

**Next** create a new class `MigrationHelper` in the project. It is going to be a static class because we need to create an extension method to start all the migrations at the application’s startup, which is what you want to do right?.

```
using System;
using DataSeedingSample.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace DataSeedingSample.Helpers
{
    public static class MigrationHelper
    {
        public static IHost MigrateDatabase(this IHost host)
        {
            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                using (var appContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DatabaseContext>())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        appContext.Database.Migrate();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error >>>> {ex}");
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
            return host;
        }
    }
}
```

**Finally** call this in the `Program` class' `Main` method like this.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args)
    .Build()
    .MigrateDatabase()
    .Run();
}
```

**UPDATE .NET 6:**

In `Program.cs` file, after line `var app = builder.Build();` add `app.MigrateDatabase();`

```
var app = builder.Build();
app.MigrateDatabase(); //<-- Add this here
```

This will seed your database every time you start the application by running all the migrations, if they are not executed already. Take a look at [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding) also.

Comment: sounds interesting, something that I thought about. lemme test it, I will feedback you soon